# Angular HTTP Request Interception - execution order for priming data

Tags: angular

I have `AuthenticationService` code implemented as an Angular Service that contains a method below. Its purpose is to extract user profile information from RESTfull API end-point. This method must complete before any request is made to the remote server.

```
  getUserProfile(): Observable<UserProfileModel> {
    const url = `${this.roleUrl}profile`;
    return this.http
      .get<UserProfileModel>(url, constants.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
        if (user.roles && user.roles.length) {
          user.selectedRoleTypeName = user.roles[0].name;
          user.selectedRoleID = user.roles[0].id;
          user.selectedRoleTypeID = user.roles[0].roleTypeId;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        return user;
        }),
        );
  }
```

getUserProfile() method above is called by an Angular component in following manner:

```
  getCurrentUserProfile() {
    let currentUser: any;
    const subscription: Subscription = this.authenticationService.getUserProfile().subscribe((response: UserProfileModel) => {
      if (response) {

        currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.currentUserName = currentUser.name || '';
        if (currentUser.roles && currentUser.roles.length) {
          this.currentUserRoles = currentUser.roles;
          this.selectedRoleTypeName = this.currentUserRoles[0].name; // Role name
        }
      }
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

I have Angular HTTP Interceptor code that should include `roleid` request header when the Browser local storage is set by the `getUserProfile()` method above.

Snippet of the Interceptor code is below:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log('HttpRoleIdInterceptor - start');

    const user: UserProfileModel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const selectedRoleID = user.selectedRoleID;
    const reqWithRoleID = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        roleid: `${selectedRoleID}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(reqWithRoleID);
  }
```

Currently, the issue is that I get the following error in the Interceptor code:
**"Cannot read property 'selectedRoleID of null".**

It seems that get user profile() doesn't set the local storage just in time for Interceptor to read data from local storage.

I'm really confused!

Comment: when does the getUserProfile exec?

Comment: @Tan - I have just updated my question to address this question.

Comment: Ok. I think it is like this. Because your interceptor will also intercept your getCurrentUserProfile() method and it hasnt exceuted so the property will always be null. In your interceptor you have to exclude the call from your getCurrentUserProfile(). And the rest will use the interceptor.

Comment: @Tan - How can I exclude the call to getCurrentUserProfile() from Interceptor please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to exclude calls from interceptor but this one is my favourite.

You can use a custom header in your getUserProfile(). Then check after it in interceptor.

example :

```
  getUserProfile(): Observable<UserProfileModel> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(SkipInterceptor, '');

    const url = `${this.roleUrl}profile`;
    return this.http
      .get<UserProfileModel>(url, {headers})
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
        if (user.roles && user.roles.length) {
          user.selectedRoleTypeName = user.roles[0].name;
          user.selectedRoleID = user.roles[0].id;
          user.selectedRoleTypeID = user.roles[0].roleTypeId;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        return user;
        }),
        );
  }
```

In the interceptor:

```
export const SkipInterceptor= 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

@Injectable()
export class SkippableInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.has(SkipInterceptor)) {
      const headers = req.headers.delete(SkipInterceptor);
      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
    }

    ...  // intercept
  }
```

}

EDIT: I saw that you had constans.httpOptions add the header in there.